# I have updated angular 15 to angular 16, after the updation there is a compile error occurs

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular16

after the updation from angular 15 to angular 16 ,the application is not working, there is an issue showing the console that "Error: Unexpected value 'JpTimeMaskModule' imported by the module 'CommonComponentModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.", How can i fix this issue?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiyRP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiyRP.jpg)

Comment: Instead of image please share the information in plain text. Image is not available.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read in the [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/16.0.0), section "Breaking Changes":

> Angular Compatibility Compiler (ngcc) has been removed and as a result Angular View Engine libraries will no longer work.

This means that libraries which don't publish an Ivy distribution won't work anymore with Angular 16. The package that you are using is on a very old Angular version, as you can see on [GitHub](https://github.com/julianobrasil/lib-time-mask). That version of Angular (v8) uses the View Engine, which is deprecated since v12. This package needs to updated to a newer Angular version, there is nothing that can be done on your side.

Answer (score 0):

If possible please share the code to import that module and the code from `JpTimeMaskModule` file. Please also check is `JpTimeMaskModule` a module or component. If it's component you need to move it from `imports` to `declarations`.

By quick searching I found below suggestions for you:

Please make sure that `JpTimeMaskModule` module is properly annotated with the @NgModule decorator. Here's what you can do:

Open the file where the `JpTimeMaskModule` module is defined

Verify that the @NgModule decorator is present before the module class definition. It should look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// Other import statements...

@NgModule({
  // Module metadata
  // ...
})
export class JpTimeMaskModule {
  // Module class definition
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The code of this module is on [GitHub](https://github.com/julianobrasil/lib-time-mask/blob/master/projects/timemask/src/lib/timemask.module.ts). As it can be seen there, the `@NgModule` annotation is present, so this is not the problem.

Comment: I am using @julianobrasil/timemask library , for time masking and it not working in  the angular 16 application, that showing the above error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ngx-scrollreveal and ngx-wow, both libraries stopped  working when updating to Angular 16, it seems that Angular 16 deprecated ViewEngine backward compatibility. In Angular 15 and lower versions there still is this backward compatibility though.